# d3.JS X-axis is removing the thousands from years

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm finishing up a project graphing US GDP using D3.JS. Unfortunately for my X-axis, D3.JS is formatting my ticks as 950, 980, 015, instead of 1950, 1980, 2015, etc. I've spent the last 45 minutes trying to google an answer. One theory I tried was using the .format option in D3.JS but I wasn't able to find a solution that way. I have also experimented with editing my input data, and that has not yielded results as well. If someone could help me change my years in the X-asix to the correct format, that would be a big help to me.

```js
let apiUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json"

GDPGraph ()


function GDPGraph () {
    fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // document.getElementById('GDP').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.data);

        var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight * .8,
            margin = 60,
            width = document.documentElement.clientWidth - margin * 2;
    
        var GDPbyQuarter = [],
            yearQuarter =[]
            labels =[[],[],[]]
            years=[]

        const svg = d3.select(document.getElementById('GDP'))
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        for(i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++){
            GDPbyQuarter.push(data.data[i][1])
        }

        for(i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++){
            yearQuarter.push(data.data[i][0])
        }

        // console.log(yearQuarter)

        for ( j = 0; j <yearQuarter.length; j++){
            var thisBar = yearQuarter[j].split('-')
            // console.log('this bar: ',thisBar);
            switch(thisBar[1]){
                case '01':
                    // console.log('case 1')
                    // console.log(thisBar[1]);
                    var quarter = ('Quarter 1');
                    break;
                case '04':
                    var quarter = ('Quarter 2');
                    break;
                case '07':
                    var quarter = ('Quarter 3');
                    break;
                case '10':
                    var quarter = ('Quarter 4');
                    break;
            }
            var year = thisBar[0]

            years.push(year);

            var dollars = (GDPbyQuarter[j])
            
            if (dollars < 1000)
           {labels.push(
                year + ' '  + quarter+ ': '+ dollars.toFixed(2) + ' billion dollars'
            )}
            else {
                labels.push(
                    year + ' '  + quarter+ ': '+ (dollars/1000).toFixed(2) + ' trillion dollars'
                )
            }

        }


        const maxNumber = d3.max(GDPbyQuarter)
    
        // console.log(maxNumber);
    
        const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, GDPbyQuarter.length])
        .range([margin , width - margin]);
    
        const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, maxNumber])
        .range([0, height - margin]);

        const yScaleReversed = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, maxNumber])
        .range([ height - margin, margin]);

        var minDate = d3.min(years),
            maxDate = d3.max(years);

        console.log('minDate: ', minDate, 'maxDate: ', maxDate)

        const yearScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([minDate, maxDate])
        .range([margin, width - margin])
        
    
    
    
        
        svg.selectAll('rect')
            .data(GDPbyQuarter)
            .enter() 
            .append('rect')
            .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i) )
            .attr("y", (d, i) => height - yScale(d) - margin)
            .attr('class', 'bar')
            .style('height', (d) => yScale(d)+'px')
            .style('width', ((1/(GDPbyQuarter.length+margin)*width)+'px'))
            .append('title')
            .attr('class', 'title')
            .text((d, i) => labels[i])
            
       
        
        const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(yearScale);
        const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScaleReversed);

        svg.append("g")
        .call(xAxis)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin ) + ")")
        .attr("position", "absolute");
        


        svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate('+margin+',0)')
            .attr('position', 'absolute')
            .call(yAxis);
    })
}
```

```css
.bar {
    fill: red;
    background-color: red;
  }

.bar:hover {
    fill: blue;
    border: 20px solid blue;
}

title {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: purple;
}



#GDP {
    position: relative;
}

#GDP > * {
    position: absolute;
}

g {
    position: absolute;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>US GDP By Quarter</h1>
        <h3>FreeCodeCamp</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="GDP">
            
    </div>
    <script src='js/app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are providing your years to a time scale as a simple number, not as a date object representing that year.  One option would be to parse your years as date obects: `var parse = d3.timeParse("%Y");`, and then use this to set the domain of your time scale: `.domain([parse(minDate), parse(maxDate)])`